# Censored Words Condition

Tags: java

I need this program to print "Censored" if userInput contains the word "darn", else print userInput, ending with newline.

I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CensoredWords {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        String userInput = "";
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        userInput = scan.nextLine;

        if(){
            System.out.print("Censored");
        }    
        else{
            System.out.print(userInput);
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Not sure what the condition for the if can be, I don't think there is a "contains" method in the string class.

Comment: don't use `string.contains()`.. It will not look for *word boundaries*. i.e, `rude` and `prude` and `prudent` are all matched if your String is *prudent*. So, your code will say *prudent* is a bad word.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution would be to use a regex with word boundary.

`if(myString.matches(".*?\\bdarn\\b.*?"))`

This prevents you from matching `sdarns`as a *rude* word. :)
[demo here](http://regex101.com/r/rZ1dP5/1)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if(userInput.contains("darn"))
{
System.out.print("Censored");
}
```

Yes that's right, String class has a method called contains, which checks whether a substring is a part of the whole string or not

Comment: Oh there is a contains method, wow it wasn't even listed here in my book. Thanks.

Comment: @beginnercoder010812 if you feel the answer is correct, then accept it as right answer otherwise it should be listed in unanswerd question.

Comment: You forgot to mention that it does not accept `String` parameter.

Comment: @beginnercoder010812 - actually `contains()` isn't the right method to be used here. If your *censored* word was *rude*, then contains will return `true` for *prudent*. is this what you want?

Comment: @maxx777 yes you are right, it accepts a CharSequence but we can pass a string as an argument and it automatically does the conversion so there is not much need to mention it :)

Answer (score 1):

Java String Class does have a [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) method. It accepts a `CharSequence` object. Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)).

Answer (score 1):

Another beginner method would be to use the indexOf function.  Try this:

```
          if (userInput.indexOf("darn") > 0) {
             System.out.println("Censored");
          }

          else {
             System.out.println(userInput);
```